# How can I handle an empty input text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<div>
                    <input class="amounts" type="text" placeholder="ENTER AMOUNT"/>
                    <a href="" data-id="@product.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-lg-add" style="margin-left:auto">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> ADD
                    </a><br />
                </div>
```

in jQuery script section, I'm trying to handle the case the user leaves it empty:

```
    $(".btn.btn-info.btn-lg-add").click(function(event){
....
    if ($(this).prev('input').val() == undefined || $(this).prev('input').val() == null) {
                url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("myHandler", "myControllerName"))';
.....
}
```

What am I doing wrong with this syntax?
- because as the user leaves the text input as empty, it does not enters the `if`

Comment: You need to show how the code shown is being called.  There's no telling what the value of `this` is without context

Comment: @Tibrogargan edited

Comment: value of a text input will not be `null` or `underfined`, try `$(this).prev('input').val() === ""`

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yes, thanks I've already figured I should use your way

Comment: `if(!$(this).prev('input').val())` is typically sufficient since empty string is falsey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to check if a `String` is null, empty, or contains only spaces:

```
function isNullOrEmpty(str){
  return !str.trim().length;
}
```

```js
 $(".btn.btn-info.btn-lg-add").click(function(event){
    if (isNullOrEmpty($(this).prev('input').val())) {
       event.preventDefault();
       alert("Value can not be empty");
    }
});
function isNullOrEmpty(str){
  return !str.trim().length;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
                    <input class="amounts" type="text" placeholder="ENTER AMOUNT"/>
                    <a href="" data-id="@product.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-lg-add" style="margin-left:auto">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> ADD
                    </a><br />
                </div>
```